# How to ignore white space in string using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having a query string and I parse it and form array of objects like,

```js
const regex = /((?:\bNOT\s+)?\w+)\s+IN\s+\('([^()]*)'\)/g;
const string = "DEVICE_SIZE IN ('036','048', '060','070') AND DEVICE_VOLTAGE IN ('1','3') AND NOT DEVICE_DISCHARGE_AIR IN ('S') AND NOT DEVICE_REFRIGERANT_CIRCUIT IN ('H', 'C')";
const data = Array.from(
  string.matchAll(regex), m =>
  ({
    [m[1]]: m[2].split("','")
  })
);
console.log(data);
```

Here `('036','048', '060','070')` has a additional white space before `060`, so the array formed looks like,

```
"DEVICE_SIZE": [
      "036",
      "048', '060",
      "070"
    ]
```

But **expected result** is

```
"DEVICE_SIZE": [
      "036",
      "048", 
      "060",
      "070"
    ]
```

Kindly help me to ignore all the white spaces before any string.

Comment: How about:
`[m[1]]: m[2].replace(/\ /g, "").split("','")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your split pattern to get right output:

```js
const regex = /((?:\bNOT\s+)?\w+)\s+IN\s+\('([^()]*)'\)/g;
const string = "DEVICE_SIZE IN ('036','048', '060','070') AND DEVICE_VOLTAGE IN ('1','3') AND NOT DEVICE_DISCHARGE_AIR IN ('S') AND NOT DEVICE_REFRIGERANT_CIRCUIT IN ('H', 'C')";
const data = Array.from(
  string.matchAll(regex), m =>
  ({
    [m[1]]: m[2].split(/',\s*'/)
  })
);
console.log(data);
```

Regex pattern `/',\s*'/` will match closing `'` and comma followed by 0 or more whitespaces and then opening `'`, this removing whitespaces from the resulting `split` array.

Comment: Could you please take a look into this post? https://stackoverflow.com/q/74699049/15916627

Comment: Sure, I will...