# How to add a keyword before string using regex in JS?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am making an application where I have a string from which I will form an array with the help of regex.

Eg..,

String: `DEVICE_SIZE IN ('036','048', '060','070')`

Output:

```
{
    "DEVICE_SIZE": [
      "036",
      "048",
      "060",
      "070"
    ]
}
```

Like this for all string, we follow the following code to get the array data.

Here if there is a **NOT** keyword before the key, then we add `NOT *key*` like `"NOT DEVICE_DISCHARGE_AIR"`

**Requirement:**

I have a string like `NOT (DEVICE_SERIES IN ('LV') AND DEVICE_VOLTAGE IN ('A','8') AND DEVICE_SIZE IN ('007','009','012','018'))`.

So here after `NOT` there is a parenthesis, so after NOT if there is a parenthesis then I need to add the key as

`"NOT DEVICE_SERIES":["LV"]`,

`"NOT DEVICE_VOLTAGE":["A", "8"]` ,

`"NOT DEVICE_SIZE": ['007','009','012','018']`

**Current scenario:**

But right now, it is not adding the NOT keyword before of key.

**Working Example:**

```js
const stringOne = "DEVICE_SIZE IN ('036','048', '060','070') AND DEVICE_VOLTAGE IN ('1','3') AND NOT DEVICE_DISCHARGE_AIR IN ('S') AND NOT DEVICE_REFRIGERANT_CIRCUIT IN ('H', 'C')";

const stringTwo = "DEVICE_SERIES IN ('LV') AND DEVICE_ELECTRICAL IN ('K') AND NOT (DEVICE_SERIES IN ('LV') AND DEVICE_VOLTAGE IN ('A','8') AND DEVICE_SIZE IN ('007','009','012','018'))";


const regex = /((?:\bNOT\s+)?\w+)\s+IN\s+\('([^()]*)'\)/g;

const getTransformedData = (string) => {
   return Array.from(
  string.matchAll(regex), m =>
  ({
    [m[1]]: m[2].split(/',\s*'/)
  })
 )
}


console.log(getTransformedData(stringOne)); // Working fine

console.log(getTransformedData(stringTwo)); // Need to include NOT infront of each key as it is union
```

How can I add NOT keyword in front of each key if it comes with the pattern of NOT and then the parenthesis like in **stringTwo**?

**Expected result:**

`"NOT DEVICE_SERIES":["LV"]`,

`"NOT DEVICE_VOLTAGE":["A", "8"]` ,

`"NOT DEVICE_SIZE": ['007','009','012','018']`

Comment: If you are not bound to use regex, and the string has many legal formats, I would recommend using a sequential parsing approach going left to right, recognizing the tokens and delimiters such as "NOT" or "IN" or "(" and ")", parsing it into a nested syntax tree, and then using a recursive function to output the list of filters.

Comment: And you might also want to think about whether to stick with the approach "not X and not Y and not Z" to be written as "not (X and Y and Z)" opposed to the boolean logic where the equivalent statement using parentheses would be "not (X or Y or Z)".

Comment: @anubhava, I need that as well. Sorry I have covered only the NOT and after paranthesis.

Comment: @anubhava,  I have missed that because it already working fine. But I need that part along with this new proposal of considering the data after NOT followed by parenthesis.

Comment: ok got it, let me get back to my laptop in few minutes and attempt a solution then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this Javascript solution for your problem:

```js
const stringOne = "DEVICE_SIZE IN ('036','048', '060','070') AND DEVICE_VOLTAGE IN ('1','3') AND NOT DEVICE_DISCHARGE_AIR IN ('S') AND NOT DEVICE_REFRIGERANT_CIRCUIT IN ('H', 'C')";
const stringTwo = "DEVICE_SERIES IN ('ALV', 'FOO') AND DEVICE_ELECTRICAL IN ('K') AND NOT (DEVICE_SERIES IN ('LV') AND DEVICE_VOLTAGE IN ('A','8') AND DEVICE_SIZE IN ('007','009','012','018'))";

const pat1 = String.raw`(\bNOT)\s+\(((?:[\w\s]+\([^)]+\))+)\)`;
const pat2 = String.raw`(\w+)\s+IN\s+\('([^()]*)'\)`;
const re1 = new RegExp(pat1 + '|' + pat2, "g");
const re2 = new RegExp(pat2, "g");
const re3 = /',\s*'/;

const getTransformedData = (string) => {
  var res = [];
  const matches = string.matchAll(re1);
  for (const match of matches) {
    if (match[1] == "NOT") {    
      res.push(...Array.from(
      match[2].matchAll(re2), m =>
      ({
        [match[1] + ' ' + m[1]]: m[2].split(re3)
      })));
    } else {
      res.push(
      ({
        [match[3]]: match[4].split(re3)
      }));
    }
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(getTransformedData(stringOne));
console.log(getTransformedData(stringTwo));
```

- Regex string `pat2` is same as what you already have
- Regex string `pat1` matches a string that has `NOT (...)` substring.
- We combine `pat1` and `pat2` to build a regex `re1` which is applied first against input string. This regex matches `NOT (...)` pattern or `word in (...)` sub-patterns.
- We capture `NOT` in capture group #1 and text inside `(...)` in capture group #2.
- When `match[1] == "NOT"` we apply `re2` again on the `match[2]` to get our desired matches
- Regex `re3` is your split regex

Comment: Thanks for your great solution bro. It helps me a lot. Thanks for your effort and time.